# MS Dynamics REST API FetchXML with a paging cookie

Tags: c#, cookies, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am using this approach available at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309717.aspx) to retrieve more than 5000 records. I am using MS Dynamics REST API together with fetchXML. My first request looks like this:

```
//ROOT.dynamics.com//api/data/v8.1/contacts?fetchXml=<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"><entity name="contact"><attribute name="emailaddress1" /></entity></fetch>
```

as a result I got set of records and page cookie for next page:

```
"@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie":"<cookie pagenumber=\"2\" pagingcookie=\"%253ccookie%2520page%253d%25221%2522%253e%253ccontactid%2520last%253d%2522%257bAF17816D-3AAE-E511-80FC-1458D043A570%257d%2522%2520first%253d%2522%257bFF672EF5-22AE-E511-80FC-1458D043A570%257d%2522%2520%252f%253e%253c%252fcookie%253e\" istracking=\"False\" />"
```

I am using this cookie in next request:

```
//ROOT.dynamics.com//api/data/v8.1/contacts?fetchXml=<fetch mapping='logical' paging-cookie='&lt;cookie page="1"&gt;&lt;contactid last="{UUID}" first="UUID}"/&gt;&lt;/cookie&gt;' page='2'><entity name='contact'><all-attributes/></entity></fetch>
```

and got

```
{
Message: "An item with the same key has already been added.",
ExceptionMessage: "An item with the same key has already been added.",
ExceptionType: "System.ArgumentException",
StackTrace: " at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector) at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataHeaders.ProcessVersioningQueryParameters() at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataHeaders..ctor(HttpRequestMessage request) at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.Extensions.EdmExtensions.GetCrmODataRequestHeader(HttpRequestMessage request) at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataRoutingConvention.SelectController(ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.SelectControllerName(ODataPath path, HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, String parameterName, IDictionary`2 values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection) at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraint(HttpRequestMessage request, Object constraint, String parameterName, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection) at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraints(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection) at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)",
ErrorCode: 500
}
```

This fetchXML works well inside of this [tool](http://msxrmtools.com/fetchxml)  but not for pure REST API request.
Maybe I have some issue with encode or structure of URL.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue, my resolution was to uri encode the ampersands in the paging cookie

```
//ROOT.dynamics.com//api/data/v8.1/contacts?fetchXml=<fetch mapping='logical' paging-cookie='%26lt;cookie page=%26quot;1%26quot;%26gt;%26lt;contactid last=%26quot;{UUID}%26quot; first=%26quot;UUID}%26quot;/%26gt;%26lt;/cookie%26gt;' page='2'><entity name='contact'><all-attributes/></entity></fetch>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks so much for this... Finally it works! I had to: 1.take the cookie in PostMan 2. unescape it two times 3.URL-Encode it and 4. replace the "&" with "%26". Now I can start to program the whole process in Node.js.. I was calling against the WebAPI btw

Answer (score 0):

For the question, how to use fetchxml pagecookie to get next page, i struggled some time to finally get it to work, assuming you have a json object response, containing the initial fetchxml call through webapi with paging cookie set to blank:

```html
var fragment = "";
var pageCookie = response["@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie"] as string;
if (pageCookie != null && pageCookie != '') {


fragment = decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(pageCookie.match(pageCookieMatch)[0]));
 fragment = fragment.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/\"/g, "&quot;");
}


let fetchxml = "<fetchxml mapping='logical' paging-cookie='"+fragment+"' page='"+ nextpage +"' count='"+pagesize+"'>...</fetchxml>";
```

The pageCookieMatch is a regexp defined as

let pageCookieMatch = /(?<=pagingcookie=['"])[a-z,A-Z,0-9,%-_.~]+/g;

I am not sure why, but for some reason you have to decode the cookie twise before you replace <>" with corresponding xml representations.